# Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi guys i have this code :

```
<!--   <button class="btn btn-info"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginpop">Login</button>   -->
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="#loginpop"  />
```

i want the asp button to act like the normal button but i get this issue`CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line`
any ideas??

Comment: It is probably the # in your event name.  That is not a legal c# name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an event called `#loginpop` for the `OnClick` event, you must have a method with the same name declared in the code behind page like below,

```
protected void #btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But in C# cs files, as the [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax758et7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) explains preprocessor directives (`#`) must appear as the first non-whitespace character that's why the error happens.

Solution would be to adhere to proper naming conventions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317109/naming-c-sharp-events-and-handlers-properly).